# Little exercise with null-sets

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

I am not very sure with this exercise, can anyone help me?

Let $(X, A, µ)$ be a measure space.
Let $µ∗ : P(X) → [0, ∞]$, $µ_∗(E) := \inf \left \{µ(F) : E ⊆ F, F ∈ B\right \}$.

I have to show that if $A ∈ B$, $N$ is a $µ$-null set, and $M ⊆ N$, then $µ_∗(A ∪ M) = µ(A)$

But is this not trivial?

What I have done is:

$µ(A ∪ M)=µ(A∪M\setminus A)=µ(A)+µ(M\setminus A)\leq µ(F)$ Since N is a $µ$-null set M is $µ$-null set and therefore $µ(M\setminus A)=0$ and for this $µ(A ∪ M)=µ(A)\leq µ(F)$ and for this $\inf \left \{µ(F) : E ⊆ F, F ∈ B\right \}=\inf(µ(A): A⊆F)$

Am I thinking something wrong?

Comment: You are on the right track: If $E\subset A\cup M$ then $E=(E\cap A)\cup (E\cap(M\setminus A)$. $\mu(E)=\mu(E\cap A)+\mu(E\cap(M\setminus A))=\mu(E\cap A)$

Comment: And what is wrong in my procedure?

Comment: From what you wrote, it seems to me that you have not completed what you want to show, namely that $\mu(A\cup M)=\mu(A)=\inf\{\mu(F): F\subset A\cup M\}$. But you are close.